# Homebrew-installed Clang fails to find headers on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, llvm-clang

So, for no apparent reason (I haven't installed a new version of clang, or changed any compiler configuration), `clang` suddenly can't find `assert.h` on my Mac.

In my development VM, running Ubuntu, both `gcc` and `clang` compile the project fine; on the host Mac OS X, `gcc` still compiles it fine, but `clang` spits out the following:

```
> make
clang -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wstrict-overflow -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c99 -m64 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -o csim csim.c cachelab.c -lm
csim.c:1:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
#include <assert.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
cachelab.c:5:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
#include <assert.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [csim] Error 1
```

Here's some further relevant information:

```
> xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
> gcc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wstrict-overflow -Wno-missing-field-initializers -std=c99 -m64 -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-parameter -o csim csim.c cachelab.c -lm
> clang -std=c99 -o csim csim.c -v
clang version 3.8.1 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
 "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/bin/clang-3.8" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name csim.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 273 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.1 -std=c99 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/ec/Dropbox/Documents/Homework/CS351/mps/04 -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 211 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.12.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/xt/wm01x2h50nv993t_csb1t5qm0000gn/T/csim-9590db.o -x c csim.c
clang -cc1 version 3.8.1 based upon LLVM 3.8.1 default target x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.8.1/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.1/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
csim.c:1:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
#include <assert.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: So did you check if the files exist in the search dirs? "ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include"" - is that correct on OS-X? It definitively is uncommon on Unix/Linux.

Comment: I'm checking with other OS X friends now, re: the former, yes, and `locate assert.h` doesn't report it existing in any of those directories: http://hastebin.com/aboyeqobih.txt

Comment: As a side-note: do you really use gcc or just the installed clang which is run with the `gcc` link? Also I'd check which path that "gcc" (whichever it is) uses. Sorry, I don't use Mac, just trying to help with common sense.

Comment: Interestingly, you're right; that gcc is running through clang, too. (That's kinda nasty? wtf?). But that makes it *even weirder* that it works?

Comment: Not, it is actually "clang running as gcc". You don't know the history of OS-x, don't you? They replaced gcc by clang some years ago, but set the link for compatibility. No wtf, but somewhat logical. Yet it can casue trouble, as both a re not identical in all aspects (options, language extensions&features. I suppose for the majority it works, though. As I wrote, I don't use Apple, I'm happy with my Linux systems:-)

Comment: I just posted an answer that should fix this problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38966585/829116