# Getting fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found #include <type_traits>, while building clang example

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang, llvm-clang

I am trying to build the [PrintFunctionNames](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/examples/PrintFunctionNames/PrintFunctionNames.cpp?view=markup) example from clang. 
However I get the following error:

```
[mac-osx:clang/examples/PrintFunctionNames] osx% clang++ -std=c++0x PrintFunctionNames.cpp
In file included from PrintFunctionNames.cpp:15:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/clang/Basic/LLVM.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:19:
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/type_traits.h:17:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
#include <type_traits>
```

System Info:

clang version 4.0.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 6197d01def79876e2c1670ced871e10b12c36241) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 24f7cd87f70ddcc91d50f77e405420c0c27853fd)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin

OSX 10.11.6

Edit 1:

on making the changes suggested by Alex, I start getting header issues. On fixing it via includes, same error is thrown again

```
% clang++ -std=c++0x PrintFunctionNames.cpp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -I../../../clang/include -I../../../../include -I../../../../../build/include
In file included from PrintFunctionNames.cpp:15:
In file included from ../../../clang/include/clang/Frontend/FrontendPluginRegistry.h:13:
In file included from ../../../clang/include/clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h:22:
In file included from ../../../clang/include/clang/Basic/LLVM.h:22:
In file included from ../../../../include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:19:
../../../../include/llvm/Support/type_traits.h:17:10: fatal error: 'type_traits' file not found
#include <type_traits>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Could you also post an output from `clang++ -v -std=c++0x PrintFunctionNames.cpp`? Now I think that isysroot doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X (macOS) has a bit different approach. You can have several Xcode installed and you compile for different platforms. 
You should use `-isysroot` option to explicitly specify against which SDK to build.

The following command should do the trick

```
clang++ -std=c++0x PrintFunctionNames.cpp -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk
```

Otherwise, please check which SDKs are installed and change the value of `isysroot` to correspond to your setup.

Comment: On making the suggested change, the compilation starts throwing header not found errors. on adding them specifically via -I, the type_trait issues is again thrown. @AlexDenisov , kindly check Edit 1. Hope I am able to explain the issue.